# Tracert not showing IP addresses instead showing something I don't recognize

Tags: networking, dns, ip-address, traceroute

I am working on a network issue but having issues with tracert. Why is it showing those bracketed numbers instead of what would look like a traditional IP address? I ran this same tracert on a different machine earlier and got traditional IPs. Below is what I am getting:

```
Tracing route to app.sabersim.com [2606:4700:20::681a:393]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  2603:9000:7100:2d01:7edb:98ff:fe04:690b
  2    10 ms    10 ms    10 ms  2603:9000:ff00:71::1
  3    12 ms     9 ms     9 ms  2607-f098-1000-4000-0000-0000-0001-006f.res6.spectrum.com [2607:f098:1000:4000::1:6f]
  4     *       11 ms     *     2607-f098-10fe-0000-0100-3800-aacc-0009.res6.spectrum.com [2607:f098:10fe:0:100:3800:aacc:9]
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *       24 ms     *     2001:1998:0:8::258
  7    18 ms    18 ms    17 ms  2001:1998:56::3d
  8    43 ms    31 ms    29 ms  2001:1998:0:8::679
  9    20 ms    28 ms    18 ms  2400:cb00:368:3::
 10    15 ms    16 ms    16 ms  2606:4700:20::681a:393
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing are either IP addresses or names given to these addresses which have reverse lookup.

The reason why these addresses appear different is that these are IPv6 addresses and you may only be familiar with IPv4 addresses.
Since you presumably specified the target using a hostname, the OS will decicde which IP protocol to use.

To manually enforce the IP protocol you can do that using either the `-4` or `-6` option in the command.